# Correct Preposition in the Phrase "Someone's back was turned ___ someone else"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I'm curious about which preposition to use in the bolded sentence:

> **Crawford’s back was turned to the supervisor**. He didn’t even bother to turn around to face the red-haired male to have a face-to-face conversation.

Should I use "Crawford's back was turned *on* the supervisor" or "Crawford's back was turned *to* the supervisor"? The first example doesn't sound right and I need a little help.

Comment: It's fine as is.  "To" means "towards" here.

Comment: Hi Martini. I made some minor edits to your question for clarity. I would also suggest that you too edit the question to mention what research you have done; otherwise, your question may be put on hold. See [this topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the bolded part of the sentence is grammatically correct.

"Was turned to" means "was facing." This phrase is also used with the head; for example, "Her head was turned to the speaker as he approached the podium."

The sentence is describing the *state* Crawford is in. "Turning one's back *on*," however, usually describes an *action* rather than a state. It's often used [metaphorically](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/turn_one%27s_back_on), whereas the "turned to" version never is.

I would take issue with the use of a mere comma to separate the two parts of that sentence, however...

Comment: Hello, ArrowCase. Though correct, this answer endorses a question that is ill-fitting on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

## Disclaimer

I conducted some basic Google searches in order to decide whether this question should be considered general-reference. According to my results, I believe that this question requires more advanced search techniques (such as the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/)) that would not be considered general-reference by an average user.

Prepositions are [a notoriously difficult feature](http://studyskills.curtin.edu.au/good-grammar/section-4-prepositions/why-so-confusing/) of languages; I have asked a couple of questions about them myself. I believe that this question will benefit future users by helping them to understand the intricacies of such issues. Additionally, my answer utilizes search techniques that users can apply to other situations.

## Background

In my Ngram searches, I have used the following specialized notation:

- `_INF` represents inflection of a word. Thus "be_INF" includes the searches "am," "is," "are," "was," "were," "be," "being," and "been."
- `*` represents a wildcard. I used this in place of "one's" in the second phrase, since the `_PRON_` (pronoun) tag was not returning results.

Note that the inflection and wildcard cannot be used in the same search element. This is why I included four Ngrams that individually inflected "turn" for the second phrase; including all variants in the same search distorted the graph.

Also note that inflection and wildcard both result in multiple results per search element. In my posted Ngrams, I have collapsed these by right-clicking on the colored terms to the right of the chart. If you visit the links to each Ngram, you can expand them again by right-clicking also in order to see frequencies of each individual result.

Many other search functions, ranging from simple to advanced, are available, only a few of which I have even delved into myself; for those interested in learning more, visit [the Ngram info page](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info).

## Discusion

Since the perception of correctness is influenced by popular usage, examining Google Ngrams to compare usages can prove insightful.

### "Back to be turned PREP"

First, let's examine the phrase used in your sentence. The phrase

> Crawford's back was turned to...

can be generalized as `back to be turned PREP`, where PREP is a preposition, in this case *on*, *to*, *towards*, or *toward*.

In this phrase, "back" is the subject, "to be" is the verb, and "turned" is a past participle. "To be" may be conjugated in any tense and aspect (e.g. "back *was* turned," "back *had been* turned," etc.).

#### Ngram

Here is [the Google Ngram for this phrase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back+be_INF+turned+to%2Cback+be_INF+turned+toward%2Cback+be_INF+turned+towards%2Cback+be_INF+turned+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cback%20be_INF%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bback%20was%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20is%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20being%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20be%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cback%20be_INF%20turned%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bback%20was%20turned%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20is%20turned%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20being%20turned%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cback%20be_INF%20turned%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bback%20was%20turned%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20is%20turned%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20being%20turned%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cback%20be_INF%20turned%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bback%20was%20turned%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20is%20turned%20on%3B%2Cc0#t3%3B%2Cback%20be_INF%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bback%20was%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20is%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20being%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20be%20turned%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cback%20be_INF%20turned%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bback%20was%20turned%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20is%20turned%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20being%20turned%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cback%20be_INF%20turned%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bback%20was%20turned%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20is%20turned%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20being%20turned%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cback%20be_INF%20turned%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bback%20was%20turned%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bback%20is%20turned%20on%3B%2Cc0) using each of these four prepositions:

[image: Google Ngram for "back to be turned PREP"]

#### Observations

Around 1800, ending this phrase with "to" and "towards" were roughly equal in popularity; usage of "toward" and "on" was negligible.

The disparity between "towards" and "toward" corresponds to general usage of the two prepositions, represented in [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toward%2Ctowards&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ctoward%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btoward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BToward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctowards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btowards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTowards%3B%2Cc0).

Around the mid-1800s, usage "to" started to increase, peaking around 1900; meanwhile, usage of "towards" remained steady until 1900, then started to decline.

Usage of "toward" rose somewhat from the late 1800s to early 1900s, reaching "towards" levels.

However, by the mid-1900s, "towards," "towards," and "on," were all equally low in usage and have remained so since. "Towards" and "toward" have recently upturned ever so slightly.

Today, "to" outweighs "towards"/"towards" 5:1, and "on" 25:1.

#### Conclusions

For the phrase "back to be turned PREP," "to" is currently the most popular preposition, although "towards" used to be comparable.

### "To Turn One's Back PREP"

Next, let's examine a related phrase: `to turn one's back PREP`

In this phrase, "to turn" is the verb and "one's back" is the object; the subject is unspecified, so the phrase may be applied to any subject. Again, "to turn" may be conjugated in any tense/aspect. "One's" may represent any possessive pronoun.

In contrast to the phrase you used, this phrase is more idiomatic, thus warranting a dedicated dictionary definition.

*Oxford Dictionaries* [defines the phrase](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/turn_one%27s_back_on) as

> **1** Ignore (someone) by turning away from them
>
> **1.1** Reject or abandon (a person or thing that one was previously involved with)

*The Free Dictionary* [defines it](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+one%27s+back+on) as

> Deny, reject; also abandon, forsake

*Thesaurus.com* lists a number of synonyms [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/turn+ones+back+on).

*Etymonline* mentions it in [its entry for back](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=back&allowed_in_frame=0).

Notice that all these entries use the preposition "on."

#### Ngram

Here are the Google Ngrams for "to turn one's back PREP", again using each of the four prepositions in question:

[**Turn**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turn%20*%20back%20on%2Cturn%20*%20back%20toward%2Cturn%20*%20back%20towards%2Cturn%20*%20back%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cturn%20%2A%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturn%20his%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20my%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20your%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20her%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20its%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20their%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20our%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20it%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20thy%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20the%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturn%20%2A%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturn%20his%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20them%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20it%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20her%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20your%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20him%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20its%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20us%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20my%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20me%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturn%20%2A%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturn%20his%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20them%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20her%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20my%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20their%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20it%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20your%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20its%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20him%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturn%20%2A%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturn%20his%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20your%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20my%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20her%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20it%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20them%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20their%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20him%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20goes%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20the%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cturn%20*%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturn%20his%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20my%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20your%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20her%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20its%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20their%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20our%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20it%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20thy%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20the%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturn%20*%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturn%20his%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20them%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20it%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20her%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20your%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20him%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20its%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20us%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20my%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20me%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturn%20*%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturn%20his%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20them%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20her%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20my%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20their%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20it%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20your%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20its%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20him%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturn%20*%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturn%20his%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20your%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20my%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20her%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20it%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20them%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20their%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20him%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20goes%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturn%20the%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0)

[image: Google Ngram for "turn one's back PREP"]

[**Turns**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turns%20*%20back%20on%2Cturns%20*%20back%20toward%2Cturns%20*%20back%20towards%2Cturns%20*%20back%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cturns%20%2A%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturns%20his%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20its%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20her%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20it%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20His%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20them%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20their%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20the%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20us%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20itself%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturns%20%2A%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturns%20his%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20her%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20it%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20us%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturns%20%2A%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturns%20his%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20her%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20its%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturns%20%2A%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturns%20his%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20her%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20its%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20it%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20us%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20them%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20the%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20you%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20him%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20sharply%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cturns%20*%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturns%20his%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20its%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20her%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20it%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20His%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20them%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20their%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20the%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20us%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20itself%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturns%20*%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturns%20his%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20her%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20it%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20us%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturns%20*%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturns%20his%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20her%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20its%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturns%20*%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturns%20his%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20her%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20its%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20it%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20us%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20them%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20the%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20you%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20him%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturns%20sharply%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0)

[image: Google Ngram for "turns one's back PREP"]

[**Turned**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turned%20*%20back%20on%2Cturned%20*%20back%20toward%2Cturned%20*%20back%20towards%2Cturned%20*%20back%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)

[image: Google Ngram for "turned one's back PREP"]

[**Turning**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turning%20*%20back%20on%2Cturning%20*%20back%20toward%2Cturning%20*%20back%20towards%2Cturning%20*%20back%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cturning%20%2A%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturning%20his%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20her%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20my%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20its%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20your%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20their%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20our%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20the%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20it%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20His%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturning%20%2A%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturning%20his%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20her%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20itself%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20the%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20it%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20him%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20them%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturning%20%2A%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturning%20his%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20her%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20them%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20the%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20its%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20it%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20him%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturning%20%2A%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bturning%20his%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20her%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20my%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20your%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20its%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20them%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20it%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20the%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20their%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20him%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cturning%20*%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturning%20his%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20her%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20my%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20its%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20your%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20their%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20our%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20the%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20it%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20His%20back%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturning%20*%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturning%20his%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20her%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20itself%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20the%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20it%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20him%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20them%20back%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturning%20*%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturning%20his%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20her%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20them%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20the%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20its%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20it%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20him%20back%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cturning%20*%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bturning%20his%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20her%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20my%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20your%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20its%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20them%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20it%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20the%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20their%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturning%20him%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0)

[image: Google Ngram for "turning one's back PREP"]

#### Observations

These Ngrams display the same trends regardless of the verb's inflection.

Around 1800, ending the phrase with "on" was marginally more popular than with "to," with 2 uses of "on" for every one of "to."

Usage of "towards" and "toward" in this phrase is virtually nonexistent. There were sporadic peaks during the 1800s. However, these never approached the frequency of "on" or "to." Since 1900, they are quite rare.

Since the mid-1850s, the frequency of both words has increased. Today, both are around 500% of their frequencies in 1850.

Usage of "on" has accelerated more quickly than that of "to," making today's usage difference between "on" and "to" average around 3:1.

#### Conclusions

For the phrase "to turn one's back PREP," "on" has always been and remains the most popular preposition.

#### Exceptions

One concern I have is that these Ngrams have no way to distinguish between literal and idiomatic usage of "to turn one's back PREP," which may have an influence on which preposition is used.

Although "on" usage has increasingly outweighed "to" usage, I have to wonder if this increase could have been influenced by a corresponding increase in usage of "to turn one's back PREP" figuratively.

Per the *Oxford Dictionaries'* [definition **1**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/turn_one%27s_back_on), the more figurative sense "ignore" appears to be extended from literally "turning away from" someone. Unfortunately, [*Etymonline*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=back&allowed_in_frame=0) makes no mention of how exactly the idiomatic meaning developed, merely stating that the meaning

> "ignore" is from early 14c

So, we have no clear indicator of whether the meaning of "to turn one's back PREP" has evolved over time and how this might have affect preposition choice.

Personally, I think that "to" sounds better with literal usage and "on" with idiomatic usage. However, this is my ***personal opinion*** and has no formally researched grammatical basis. I did find some anecdotal evidence that supports this view at [*Quora*](https://www.quora.com/English-language-What-is-the-difference-between-turn-your-back-on-and-turn-your-back-to-When-saying-Pardon-my-back).

## Summary

According to the trends discussed above as well as my personal "ear" for grammar, I would recommend the following usage:

- Use the preposition "to" following a phrase structured `back to be turned`.

  - E.g. "Crawford's back was turned *to* his supervisor.
- Use the preposition "to" following a phrase structured `to turn one's back` when it is used *literally* to mean that one has pivoted so that their back is facing someone.

  - E.g. "Crawford turned his back *to* his supervisor in order to check that the office door was locked."
- Use the preposition "on" following a phrase structured `to turn one's back`when it is used *figuratively* to mean that one has ignored, rejected, or abandoned someone.

  - E.g. "Crawford turned his back *on* his supervisor when he started gossiping about their private conversations with all of his coworkers."

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is grammatically correct. The author is using the word **to** as an alternative preposition to **toward**.

See the second definition on dictionary.com ([http://www.dictionary.com/browse/to?s=t](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/to?s=t/)):

> (used for expressing direction or motion or direction toward
>   something) in the direction of; toward:
>   *from north to south.*